# How to achieve dynamic dash based on line length on Animated setLineDash on Canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, html5-audio

I am trying to make a Audiovisualizer with Canvas. The goal is to have a dynamic wave that is dashed.
The wave looks good when using `bezierCurveTo` for the wave and `setLineDash` for the dashed effect.

This works for a static line, but when the line is animated and the curves changes in size, the dashes are distributed over a longer line. with rapid movement this looks jittery.

If i could change the `setLineDash` length of the stroke dynamically with the amplitude of the curve correctly, i believe it could look much better.

i tried it (on line 40 of the pen) without luck. I just cant figure out how to calculate the right length of the dash, the result is always a more or less full line, no dashes.

the Pen:

https://codepen.io/ascheschleier/pen/gOZrYdY

edit:
I experimented with `createPattern` to overlay an image over the line, that is almost how i want it to be, but the edges of the dashes are always vertical this way, which just looks wrong.
see https://codepen.io/ascheschleier/pen/OJrNPNQ

Comment: So you're trying to get an effect as if the line was actually morphing into the curve, and so that the dash on the higher curves are actually longer so that they look as if they were stretched, right?

Comment: exactly that! well the main goal would be to get rid of the jitter and thats the only way i can think of. if you come up with a different approach, it is welcome too, of course.